# How To Use exclude_line in filebeat

Tags: logstash, filebeat

172.11.11.11 - - [01/Dec/2020:05:49:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1875 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"

am using filebeat in application server aws instance and elk in other instance.

am getting logs like these in message level, i want to exlude these lines.how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a pattern for the logs you want to exclude? For example, does it will always contains a specific text like `"ELB-HealthChecker/2.0`?

Comment: 172.11.11.11 - - [01/Dec/2020:05:49:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1875 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"                                                                                                     -thanks for your reply and  this is what my log like this, i dont have pattern, is it possible to exclude these?

Comment: In a simple way you can do something like `exclude_lines: ['ELB-HealthChecker']`, which excludes all lines that contains the text `ELB-HealthChecker`. You can use more complex regex based patterns as well, if required. To use this in `filebeat.yml` please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html#:~:text=A%20list%20of%20regular%20expressions,Empty%20lines%20are%20ignored.

Comment: i have two applications running as docker containers, for one app i have configured logstash pipeline as follow.
input {
beats {
port => 5044
}
tcp {
port => 5000
}
}
filter {
json {
source => "message"
remove_field => "message"
}
if [level] == 10 {
mutate {
add_field => { "log-level" => "trace" }
}
}
if [level] == 20 {
mutate {
add_field => { "log-level" => "debug" }
}
}
for other app, i am getting log like this,
info: ::ffff:172.11.11.11 - GET / 123 - 1.232 ms

my requirement is if info in message its has to add "info" in log-level.
how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

@Syam has already answered you correctly but after reading your requirement further, I suggest you use the filter section in logstash and apply this.

```
filter {
      if [message] =~ 'info' or if [message] =~ 'INFO' or if [message] =~ 'Info' {
          mutate {
            replace => { "LOG-LEVEL" => "INFO" }
          }
      }
  }
```

GOOD LUCK :)